# IObservable to produce results in infinite loop

Tags: c#, loops, windows-phone-8, system.reactive, observable

This is a code that I've developed so far:

```
var observable = Observable.Create<string>(async observer =>
{
    var wc = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
    observer.OnNext(await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://ya.ru"));
});

observable.Subscribe(
    res => Debug.WriteLine("got result: {0}", res), 
    exc => Debug.WriteLine("exception: {0}", exc.Message)
);
```

This correctly fetches website's data and triggers my callback once. What I want is to have an infinite loop that acts like this: await result -> call `OnNext` -> wait `n` seconds -> repeat an operation.

Creating an `Observable.Interval` and `SelectMany` it into my `Observable` won't quite do because this will be querying a website for a fixed periods of time. I want the next call to be triggered only after the previous succeeds or fails. What's the most elegant and concise way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without changing too much of your code, you could effectively concat a delay after the yield, and then repeat the whole thing indefinitely.

```
var observable = Observable.Create<string>(async observer =>
{
    var wc = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
    observer.OnNext(await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://ya.ru"));
});

observable
    .Concat(Observable.Empty<string>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    .Repeat()
    .Subscribe(
      res => Debug.WriteLine("got result: {0}", res), 
      exc => Debug.WriteLine("exception: {0}", exc.Message)
    );
```

However, there's better ways of doing this, because in the previous instance you're creating a new WebClient every second. Instead, you could do something like this...

`using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;`

```
var observable = Observable.Using(() => new WebClient(), (client) =>
    client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://ya.ru")
        .ToObservable()
        .Concat(Observable.Empty<string>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
        .Repeat()
        );
```

And if you wanted to repeat on errors, you could add `Retry`...

```
var observable = Observable.Using(() => new WebClient(), (client) =>
    client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://ya.ru")
        .ToObservable()
        .Retry(3)
        .Concat(Observable.Empty<string>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
        .Repeat()
        );
```

Comment: This version doesn't repeat on errors.

Comment: Oh should it repeat on errors? That's not what the original example does...

Comment: Why was this down-voted? It does exactly as the OP requests, and it's quite good practice.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Yeah it should, I just was not sure how to implement it :) Thanks for a detailed reply.

Comment: @Anton Absolutely. Rx can be tricky, but once you understand all of the operators it's like "ohhhhhhhhh..."

Comment: I down-voted it when it wasn't retrying on errors. Since you edited it I un-down voted... But I'm not upvoting because this is rehashing material covered in previous answers really... Am I being too harsh?

Comment: Down-votes are great for democracy, but are ambiguous by nature.